# How to specify and clean/delete the rows?

Tags: r

For example, here is the dataframe. I want to delete the rows if the age difference in each ProjectNumber is less than 5. Within ProjectNumber = 1, the age difference are 6(56-50) so rows in ProjectNumber 1 is maintained. In ProjectNumber2, the age difference are 2(37-35), so 3 rows in ProjectNumber 2 will be deleted. How can I do that? There are thousands of Project Number in real data set so can't really do it mannually. The key problem is how to specify these rows and delete them. Thank you.

| ProjectNumber | Age |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 |
| 1 | 52 |
| 1 | 53 |
| 1 | 55 |
| 1 | 56 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 36 |
| 2 | 37 |
| 3 | 40 |
| 3 | 41 |
| 3 | 42 |
| 3 | 43 |
| 3 | 45 |
| 3 | 46 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akrun's answer is top. Here: cumbersome but leads to the goal:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ProjectNumber) %>% 
  mutate(diff_Age = max(Age) - min(Age)) %>% 
  subset(!diff_Age < 5) %>% 
  select(-diff_Age)
```

Output:

```
   ProjectNumber   Age
           <int> <int>
 1             1    50
 2             1    52
 3             1    53
 4             1    55
 5             1    56
 6             3    40
 7             3    41
 8             3    42
 9             3    43
10             3    45
11             3    46
```

Answer (score 5):

Base R variants:

1. `aggregate` then `merge`. This version is good if you have more than one "key" (`ProjectNumber` here).

   ```r
   keep <- subset(aggregate(Age ~ ProjectNumber, data = df1,
                            FUN = function(z) diff(range((z))) >= 5), Age)
   keep
   #   ProjectNumber  Age
   # 1             1 TRUE
   # 3             3 TRUE

   merge(df1, keep[,1,drop=FALSE], by = "ProjectNumber")
   #    ProjectNumber Age
   # 1              1  50
   # 2              1  52
   # 3              1  53
   # 4              1  55
   # 5              1  56
   # 9              3  40
   # 10             3  41
   # 11             3  42
   # 12             3  43
   # 13             3  45
   # 14             3  46
   ```
2. `aggregate` then `%in%`:

   ```r
   ### 'keep' from above
   subset(df1, ProjectNumber %in% keep$ProjectNumber)
   ```
3. `ave` then simple subset:

   ```r
   keep <- ave(df1$Age, df1$ProjectNumber, 
               FUN = function(z) diff(range(z)) >= 5) > 0
   keep
   #  [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
   df1[keep,]
   #    ProjectNumber Age
   # 1              1  50
   # 2              1  52
   # 3              1  53
   # 4              1  55
   # 5              1  56
   # 9              3  40
   # 10             3  41
   # 11             3  42
   # 12             3  43
   # 13             3  45
   # 14             3  46
   ```

Answer (score 2):

We do a group by `filter` i.e. grouped by 'ProjectNumber', check the `diff`erence of `range` of 'Age' is greater than or equal to 5

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ProjectNumber) %>% 
  filter(diff(range(Age)) >=5) %>%
  ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ProjectNumber = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Age = c(50L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 45L, 46L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, .SD[diff(range(Age)) >= 5], ProjectNumber]
    ProjectNumber Age
 1:             1  50
 2:             1  52
 3:             1  53
 4:             1  55
 5:             1  56
 6:             3  40
 7:             3  41
 8:             3  42
 9:             3  43
10:             3  45
11:             3  46
```